# Determine which character was used in String.Split()

Tags: c#, .net, string, split

If I am using **String.Split()** how can I find out which character caused the split? For instance, when "**Apple|Car**" splits, I want to know that it did so via the pipe character and not a comma or hyphen.

When I see the "**Car**" item, I'd want to know it was split from "**Apple**" with a pipe, and split from "**Plane**" with a comma.

```cs
var splitChars = new Char [] {'|', ',', '-'};
        
string item1 = "Apple|Car,Plane-Truck";

var mySplit = item1.Split(splitChars);
```

Comment: By looking back at the original? You could've split on all those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
string myMessage = "Apple|Car,Plane-Truck";

//Break apart string
var splits = myMessage.Split(new Char[] { '|', ',', '-' });

int accumulated_length = 0;
foreach (string piece in splits)
{
    accumulated_length += piece.Length + 1;
    if (accumulated_length <= myMessage.Length)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} was split at {1}", piece, myMessage[accumulated_length - 1]);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} was the last one", piece);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It will split on all of them in the example you've given. but in general, you would just see which of the defined split characters are contained in the string:

```
var sourceString = "Apple|Car,Plane-Truck";
var allSplitChars = new[] {'|', ',', '-', '.', '!', '?'};

// Find only the characters that are contained in the source string
List<char> charsUsedToSplit = allSplitChars.Where(sourceString.Contains).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Any characters in the list will be used for the split.. can you clarify what you're actually trying to do? in your example the tokens after the split will be "Apple", "Car", "Plane", "Truck" so each of your characters will be used to split..

If you're trying to determine which character caused the split for each token, then perhaps you might implement the split yourself and keep track:

```
List<Tuple<String, Char>> Splitter(string msg, char[] chars) {
  var offset = 0;
  var splitChars = new HashSet<char>(chars); 
  var splits = new List<Tuple<String, Char>>();
  for(var idx = 0; idx < msg.Length; idx++) {
    if (splitChars.Contains(msg[idx])) {
      var split = Tuple.Create(msg.Substring(offset, idx - offset), msg[idx]);
      splits.Add(split);
      offset = idx + 1;
    } 
  }
  return splits;
}

string myMessage = "Apple|Car,Plane-Truck";
var splits = Splitter(myMessage, new [] {'|', ',', '-'});
foreach (string piece in splits)
{
    Console.WriteLine("word: {0}, split by: {1}", piece.Item1, piece.Item2);
}
```